# how to add a non-existent method name to suggest list under Zend Studio?

Tags: php, zend-studio, phpdoc

I wrote a class like this :

```
class config {
    private $conf;

    public function __call( $confName, $args ){
        if (  0 == count($args) && isset($this->conf[$confName]) ){
            return $this->conf[$confName];
        }
        else {
            $this->conf[$confName] = $args[0];
            return $this;
        }
    }
}
```

and 
$conf = new config();

but I wanna get the suggest list when I input $conf->,

is there any ideal or it's impossible to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class config {
    private $conf;

    public function none_existent_method1(){
        // forward the call to __call(__FUNCTION__, ...)
        return call_user_func(array($this, '__call'),
            __FUNCTION__, func_get_args());
    }

    public function none_existent_method2(){
        // forward the call to __call(__FUNCTION__, ...)
        return call_user_func(array($this, '__call'),
            __FUNCTION__, func_get_args());
    }

    public function __call( $func, $args ){
        if (  0 == count($args) && isset($this->conf[$func]) ){
            return $this->conf[$func];
        }
        else {
            $this->conf[$func] = $args[0];
            return $this;
        }
    }
}
```

Just add the methods and forward them to `__call` yourself.

*There are other ways but all require you declare the functions.*

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Zend Studio honors the @method tag in the class docblock, like Eclipse PDT does, then perhaps that will give you what you're after.

```
/**
 * Config class
 * @method mixed aMagicMethod()  a magic method that could return just about anything
 * @method int   anotherMethod() a magic method that should always return an integer
 */
class config { ...
```

Comment: This is a goog way, but some developers would not or forget update comment when they modify the code, then the comment method would be danger for others.

Comment: But, because you're using __call(), you are not actually defining any method names in your code.  As such, there is no place in that class to list method names, except the @method tag.  If you are actually defining methods in code, then __call() should not be necessary to reach those methods.  Perhaps I'm missing some aspect of your use case.

Comment: yeah, I should remove __call() method, or just rename to _call().